# Javascript S3 GET Bucket (List Objects) Formatting?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, get

I'm trying to get a xml response from AWS s3 as outlined in this doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html

I'm not sure how to integrate these paramiters:

```
GET /?list-type=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Authorization: authorization string
```

Into the "open" statement of a standard AJAX code like this:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

I'm thinking something like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("list-type", "2");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Date", "00/00/2018");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "authorization string");
```

Any insight on how to do this would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

This is the documentation for the AWS Javascript SDK. I'm not sure what XML you are trying to get, but what you are looking for is probably in there.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: "examplebucket", 
  Key: "HappyFace.jpg"
 };
 s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

Comment: The way that I understood the documentation, if you send a GET request with the listed params, it will return a XML object list, look at the bottom of the documentation page for an example.